# Searching for a value in an ArrayList that is stored in a HashMap

Tags: java, search, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to figure out how to retrieve a value that is stored in an ArrayList, stored in a Hashmap.

Here's what I have:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Record>> records = new HashMap<>();
```

The key in this hashmap is not what I am looking for. There is a method inside of the Record object called `getRecordId()` and I want to be able to evaluate whether or not this `recordId`, through an if statement, exists in the ArrayList.

Example:

```
if(records.values.exists(recordId)){ ...do something ...}
```

Essentially, I want to loop through all the values in the ArrayList to see if that record ID exists, and if it does, I will store the key and compute some things. How to I do this?

Edit: right after posting this question, I think I am on to something. How about this:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Record>>> entrySet = records.entrySet();
for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Record>> data : entrySet)
{
    for(Record entry : data.getValue())
    {
        if(recordId.equals(entry.getRecordId()))
        {
            // Do something here
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

I need to leave the loops if the record ID has been found, because record IDs are unique.

Comment: Do you want to find some id in Record and return key, list of records or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use here `Hashmap.entrySet()` to get the list of all the keys, and iterate through that key set, and check if `recordId` exists in the ArrayList for that particular iteration, then store the key and do your computations.

If you are not sure about the syntax and usage of `entrySet` then you can look into it here - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-map-java/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax :

```
records.forEach((k, v) -> {
    if (v.contains(recordId)) {
        // do something with 'k'
    }
});
```

Here we are iterating over the map using `forEach`. The `k` stands for the key and the `v` stands for the value. You can also achieve the same using the `entrySet`

```
records.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
    if (e.getValue().contains(recordId)) {
        // do something with 'e.getKey()'
    }
});
```

Comment: This lambda expression is great! Edited my original post, can you please verify that what I did is correct?

Comment: Yup, it is. If my answer helped, upvote and accept! Break would exit only 1 loop.

Comment: The problem here is that `contains` will always return `false`, because you are comparing `"your_id"` (which is a string) against each element of the array list, which is a `Record` instances.

Comment: Right! I checked it in my IDE with String as I don't have the Record class :) But I think he got the point. Thanks for that, made the edit.

Comment: If that record has been found in the ArrayList, then I need to modify some fields and return. I think a nested foreach loop would be more appropriate in that case.

Comment: Hold on, you can't keep editing your question with different requirements after the answer! :) S.O. doesn't work like that. You will need to ask another question in that case. Also *"do some things"* is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear that I needed to break out of both loops when the record is found in the ArrayList. Record IDs are unique and if I find the record that I am looking for, I would be wasting time looping through the rest of the list because that record would not be found anywhere else. Also, It doesn't matter what I do in "do something". As long as I get to the record that I am looking for, the rest isn't tough. Thanks for your help and I apologize if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList> data : records) {
            ArrayList list = (ArrayList) data.getValue();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                if (list.get(i).equals(recordId)) {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Java 8` you can use `stream`:

```
//List of keys which contains your desired Record at it's value(ArrayList)
List<String> requiredListOfKeys = records.keySet().stream()
                                                  .filter(x -> records.get(x)
                                                  .contains(record))
                                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to go would be to stream the map values, and for each value (which is a list), stream it and find the first `Record` instance that matches your search criteria. Then, if such record was found, do whatever you want to do with it:

```
boolean found = records.values().stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream) // or .flatMap(list -> list.stream())
    .filter(entry -> recordId.equals(entry.getRecordId()))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(entry -> {
        // do something with the found record
    });
```